# wordpress image carousel of logged in user's images

Tags: wordpress, carousel

How do you have an image carousel show only the logged in user's images? I can upload images to a carousel but can only choose between ALL users' images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does not keep information in the database on the logged in status. Logged in user just have a cookie in his browser.

Yoi can use some hook when a user logs in, and maintain this list by yourself in the database. Also, you can use some hook on logout. Additionally, you should use cookie expiration time to make a reasonable estimation if user is still logged in.

It is not so simple and straightforward task.